# Fill jPanel from constructor

Tags: java, swing, constructor, jpanel, addition

I'm trying to fill a jPanel2 inside the jPanel1, from the constructor of this jPanel1.
Something like this.

```
public jPanel1(){

    initComponents(); // here is created the jPanel2
    JButton jb= new JButton();
    jb.setBounds(new java.awt.Rectangle(0, 22, 400, 270));
    this.jPanel2.add(jb);
}
```

The Jbutton is not showing. Anyway when I print the jPanel2 bounds from the constructor, I get this:

'java.awt.Rectangle[x=0,y=0,width=0,height=0]'

What I can't understand is that, when I add this Jbutton from another button listener, for example, it works well.
I guess that in some moment of the lifecycle of the JPanel1, the jPanel2 is bounded, but I can't figure out where. 
Could anybody help please?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JPanel` by default uses a `FlowLayout`.  Instead, you should try using a `BorderLayout`

```
public jPanel1(){
    initComponents(); // here is created the jPanel2
    JButton jb= new JButton();
    jPanel2.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    this.jPanel2.add(jb);
}
```

The initial problem you're facing is that the size of the parent container (`jPanel1`) is unknown until the container is laid out...Better to let the layout managers do there job ;)